# What is the name of this error? $\frac{\sum_i{(x_i-\hat{x}_i)^2}}{\sum_ix_i^2}$

Tags: calculus, estimation, mean-square-error

Assume we use a machine learning algorithm for regression to estimate variables such that $\hat{x}_i$ estimates $x_i$. What is the following error called?

$$\frac{\sum_i{(x_i-\hat{x}_i)^2}}{\sum_ix_i^2}$$

It is similar to NMSE or MSE. Does it have a name?

Comment: Mathematically, it is equivalent to the MMSE (**M**inimum **M**ean-**S**quare **E**rror) so it can be named such.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz I do not see how it is mathematically equivalent to MMSE. Can you let me know how?

Comment: What meaning does the formula have if $x_i=0$ for all $i$?

Comment: I say it because as long as the fraction exists, an optimization takes place over $\hat x_i$s not $x_i$s.

Comment: @BarryCipra good point.

Comment: @Albert A little more context is helpful.

Comment: @calculus I added some.